# Is it possible to extend an extention in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

Is it possible to extend Joomla Extensions? 
For example in your Joomla extension you want to end you have an XML file which contains a bunch of data entries for what type of input can be added to a article/file/tag (Specifically RS-FILES files). 
We would like this extend of this extension to add entries to this file. 
We could of course just modify this XML file and life would be good, however if the extension gets modified then we lose all updates. 
If we had an extension/plugin that would modify the XML file on update and some other source code files (via our code logic), then it would allow for updates (to a certain extent). Is there anyway of doing this?
Currently RS-Files allows for 10-15 entries for information on a file, but there isn't a way to add a "new" entry unless you modify the entries XML and several locations in the source code.

Comment: Joomla questions are welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the extension before, but what you're asking for sounds to me like a simple override.
More details you can find here: [How to override the component mvc from the Joomla! core](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core)